# split multiple non-delimited numbers to two significant digits

Tags: bash, awk

I need to split a long non-delimited series of numbers using awk.  How would I split this:

```
91.5799.3677.48107.5981.26
```

using awk to produce this:

```
91.57
99.36
77.48
107.59
81.26
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be easier with `egrep`:

```
s='91.5799.3677.48107.5981.26'
egrep -o '[^.]*.[0-9]{2}' <<< "$s"
91.57
99.36
77.48
107.59
81.26
```

Comment: egrep sounds like a good solution, thanks.  I was piping the output into awk from an xpath query which is returning these numbers, can I use a backwards pipe or will bash parse the egrep before the output line?

Comment: You can just pipe the output to egrep as `egrep -o '[^.]*.[0-9]{2}'`

Answer (score 1):

If GNU grep is not available and Perl is acceptable:

```
perl -pe's|\...(?!\Z)|$&\n|g' infile
```

GNU awk:

```
awk 'NF&&$0=$0RT' RS='\\...' infile
```

Comment: Used the egrep solution above, thanks for the solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` as requested..

```
awk 'NR==1 {s=$1} NR>1 {e=substr($1,1,2);print s "." e;s=substr($1,3)}' RS="." <<< "91.5799.3677.48107.5981.26"
91.57
99.36
77.48
107.59
81.26
```

---

Another version

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i==".") f=i;printf "%s"(f&&i==f+2?RS:""),$i}}' FS=""
91.57
99.36
77.48
107.59
81.26
```

Comment: Used the egrep solution above, thanks for the solution though.